# Opening a winform from an IronPython shell without blocking the shell or the form

Tags: winforms, ironpython, modal-dialog

I'm starting a winform from an IronPython shell. My form is then calling a script which runs for some hours and writes output to the shell.

While the script is running, the GUI is blocked (I cannot hit any buttons or minimize it).

I tried these approaches:

1. When I open the form with ShowDialog(), the form stays in front. I cannot put the python shell in front and scroll the written comments. I have to close the form first, but this is not what I want.
2. When I open the form with Show(), I can put the python shell in front and I can scroll it, but when I close the python shell (before closing the winform), the winform stays open and is now blocked; I can only kill it using the Task Manager.

So, what I want is the situation like in case 2, but when I close my python shell, the winform should be automatically closed too.

After reading some other questions here I thought about starting the form with Show() but setting the Modal property to true, but when I try to do this from the shell it says the property is private. I created the form in Visual Studio, so is it maybe possible to set the Modal property there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to get your UI to process the windows events for the application by calling:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

The reason why the Modal window is working for you is because it automatically behind the scenes loops and automatically process windows messages.

Here is a sample C# and IronPython code to simulate a long running script showing a Windows Form

```
var py = Python.CreateEngine();
var script = @"
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import *
from System.Threading import *
frm = Form()
frm.Show()
while True:
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    Application.DoEvents()
";
var source = py.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);
var scope = py.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
```

Notice the python code is just indefinately looping (Simulating your long running script)
It is important that your script has the opportunity to be able to call into DoEvents to update the UI. If this is NOT the case and your script will block for a long time on single calls, you might consider running the script itself in a seperate thread, this will allow you to leave the main thread available to process messages.

Just be careful when creating threads the Winforms doesn't like to be created or updated from a seperate thread, so make sure you are calling your UI update methods by synchronizing them to the main thread.

With the sample code above, when I close the console window, the Winform is also automatically destroyed by windows. So I am not seeing the problem you describe.